# How do you gain access to the helper methods inside the controller with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller, helper, viewcontext

I want to use a method i have in my helper inside my controller.
I don't know how to use the view_context which i've heard could do the trick

Comment: Generally, the opposite is made: controllers methods are used as helpers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As apneadiving said, make it a controller method and make that a helper method.

```
application_controller.rb

  helper_method :do_stuff

  def do_stuff
    #this method is available in all controllers and views
```

Answer (score 0):

I vote for @apneadiving's idea. But here goes:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include SomeHelper
end
```